# Dynamically add file versions to a Carrierwave Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, zip, carrierwave

I'd like to use a CarrierWave uploader to unpack an uploaded zip file containing a variable number of files and store each of the files in the same location where the zip file is stored. The files should be made available in the model holding the uploader.

I just need a starting point on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is 100% relevant but I have just made a `Gallery` controller that accepts a zip file, and adds the contents of this zipfile as `Images` which are associated with the `Gallery` model.

I accomplished this by using the Zippy gem, along with a home rolled FilelessFile class that extends StringIO.

Each file in the zipfile is saved as an individual carrierawave mounted `Image` model.

In your case I guess you could have a `File` model (and a File uploader) which `belongs_to` your main model, and your main model have a `has_many` relation to the `File` model.

For an exempt of the controller and the "magic" fileless handling see: https://gist.github.com/1963073

**Note:** Please note that I do not use CarrierWave for handling the zipfile upload, I use CarrierWave to save the files inside the zipfile. If you need to store the zipfile as well you could create a ZipFile uploader and mount a zipfile on the main model along with the individual files or just reuse the `File` uploader and save the zipfile in a field on the main model.